# Python build application failed when launched from finder

Tags: python, macos, qt

Using python 3, QT5 under osx, I build an application from source code.

When I run it directly from the binary, it works well.
When I run it launching `open -a sakia.app` it works well.

But when I try to launch it from the launchpad, or from finder, it fails after few seconds without showing any window on screen.

Nothing more in logs than:

`May 13 20:01:57 my-macbook com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (sakia.5432[4022]): Service exited with abnormal code: 255`

I haven't been able to see on google cases where open command works and direct app opening doesn't.

I think I have no issues with the file locations, but I can not ensure it, I don't know how to check it precisely since there are logs nowhere...

What should I look for? Any idea about the debugging or the cause?

Edit:

here is my Info.plist :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict><key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>sakia</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
<string>True</string>
<key>LSBackgroundOnly</key>
<string>False</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>0.0.0</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>MacOS/sakia.bin</string>
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>sakia.ico</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>sakia</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>sakia</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/tmp/test.stderr</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Maybe there's some library in the same directory as the `.app` file, so the executable attempts to load it but fails when moved into another directory.

Comment: I don't understand ?

I don't move the .app in the 3 cases mentionned (started from binary, started using "open", started from finder.

Comment: In Finder, right click the app and then click Show Package Contents. Then under Contents > MacOS, see if you can open the Unix Executable version of the program ( this should have the same filename as your app ) . That will at least split the problem in half for you.

Comment: @JacobIRR : the executable is named sakia.bin, but it doesn't execute it if I double click, it creates a sakia.bin.cpgz...

Comment: Sounds like the file is not executable from the system. If you drag the file into Terminal, you'll see its exact path (actually drag it there instead of assuming you know the path to rule out human error.) Then you can stat it: `stat -c %a <file path goes here>`. Let me know what you get back

Comment: @JacobIRR : (sakia-env) me@my-macbook [~/Documents/Perso/Duniter/sakia.git] % stat dist/sakia.app/Contents/MacOS/sakia.bin                                                                                                      - (21:14)
16777220 4178596 -rwxr-xr-x 1 me admin 0 3974988 "May 13 20:58:37 2017" "May 13 19:26:07 2017" "May 13 19:26:07 2017" "May 13 19:26:07 2017" 4096 7768 0 dist/sakia.app/Contents/MacOS/sakia.bin

Comment: stat -f %a dist/sakia.app/Contents/MacOS/sakia.bin                                                                                                   
1494701917

Comment: I think the executability is fine. This may relate to some of the app settings that populate the Info.plist file in the package. Not sure about the way QT5 handles that stuff though.

Comment: @JacobIRR just added the generated Info.plist generated. This is generated by pyinstaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application is opening a file that get a special character in it, this makes the application failing. (ğ)

When you are opening the app from command line, you get

```
locale.getpreferredencoding(False) = UTF-8
```

But if you open directly from GUI (launchpad or finder) you get

```
locale.getpreferredencoding(False) = US-ASCII
```

I don't really understand precisely the behavior leading to this, but just by adding this in info.Plist makes it

```
<dict>
    <key>LANG</key>
    <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
    <key>LC_ALL</key>
    <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
</dict>
```